# Azure Function App - Exception: AssertionError: Number of bodies and metadata mismatched

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, debezium

I'm developing Function App on Azure that handles messages sent to Azure EventHub. Messages are generated by Debezium (CDC on PostgreSQL). Messages are in JSON format.
Mostly code below works without problem but for specific messages (deletion) I receive error that I do not understand...

```
[2021-10-22T16:23:46.679Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2021-10-22T16:23:50.220Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000002A92F406'.
[2021-10-22T16:25:33.353Z] Executing 'Functions.testEventHubTrigger' (Reason='(null)', Id=ce31cdac-24d4-4ff1-a8d9-3f95bc8b760a)
[2021-10-22T16:25:33.355Z] Trigger Details: PartionId: 0, Offset: 12885023368-12885023368, EnqueueTimeUtc: 2021-10-22T16:25:33.2280000Z-2021-10-22T16:25:33.2280000Z, SequenceNumber: 228-228, Count: 1
[2021-10-22T16:25:33.417Z] New event detected
[2021-10-22T16:25:33.420Z] Event message: {"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"default":0,"field":"departmentid"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"groupname"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.time.MicroTimestamp","version":1,"default":0,"field":"modifieddate"}],"optional":true,"name":"Adventureworks.humanresources.department.Value","field":"before"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"default":0,"field":"departmentid"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"groupname"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.time.MicroTimestamp","version":1,"default":0,"field":"modifieddate"}],"optional":true,"name":"Adventureworks.humanresources.department.Value","field":"after"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"version"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"connector"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Enum","version":1,"parameters":{"allowed":"true,last,false"},"default":"false","field":"snapshot"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"db"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"sequence"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"schema"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"table"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"txId"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"lsn"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"xmin"}],"optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source","field":"source"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"op"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"total_order"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"data_collection_order"}],"optional":true,"field":"transaction"}],"optional":false,"name":"Adventureworks.humanresources.department.Envelope"},"payload":{"before":{"departmentid":186,"name":"","groupname":"","modifieddate":0},"after":null,"source":{"version":"1.6.2.Final","connector":"postgresql","name":"Adventureworks","ts_ms":1634919842294,"snapshot":"false","db":"Adventureworks","sequence":"[\"1040891432\",\"1040891432\"]","schema":"humanresources","table":"department","txId":203668,"lsn":1040927480,"xmin":null},"op":"d","ts_ms":1634919933086,"transaction":null}}
[2021-10-22T16:25:33.439Z] Executed 'Functions.testEventHubTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=ce31cdac-24d4-4ff1-a8d9-3f95bc8b760a, Duration=94ms)
[2021-10-22T16:25:33.613Z] Executing 'Functions.testEventHubTrigger' (Reason='(null)', Id=a693051f-790c-4b90-af21-5792a386c7a1)
[2021-10-22T16:25:33.616Z] Trigger Details: PartionId: 0, Offset: 12885026456-12885032224, EnqueueTimeUtc: 2021-10-22T16:25:33.2280000Z-2021-10-22T16:25:33.3060000Z, SequenceNumber: 229-231, Count: 3
[2021-10-22T16:25:33.636Z] Executed 'Functions.testEventHubTrigger' (Failed, Id=a693051f-790c-4b90-af21-5792a386c7a1, Duration=23ms)
[2021-10-22T16:25:33.639Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.testEventHubTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: AssertionError: Number of bodies and metadata mismatched
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 382, in _handle__invocation_request
    args[pb.name] = bindings.from_incoming_proto(
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\bindings\meta.py", line 87, in from_incoming_proto
    return binding.decode(datum, trigger_metadata=metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure\functions\eventhub.py", line 108, in decode
    return cls.decode_multiple_events(data, trigger_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure\functions\eventhub.py", line 159, in decode_multiple_events
    raise AssertionError('Number of bodies and metadata mismatched')
.
```

Below code of my function:

```
from typing import BinaryIO, List
import logging
import json
import psycopg2

import azure.functions as func

def main(events: List[func.EventHubEvent]):
    for event in events:
        logging.debug('New event detected')
        logging.debug('Event message: %s',
                        event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
        row = json.loads(event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

Error appears when iterator changes in for loop (as it would try to read something that does not exist?)

Please help me to debug this...

EDIT
It seems that Debezium when delete operation is done on PostgeSQL is generating two messages. One with payload and second which is called "Tombstone" message. (https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.7/connectors/postgresql.html)
The second message is empty, which most probably is causing above exception.

> PostgreSQL connector events are designed to work with Kafka log
> compaction. Log compaction enables removal of some older messages as
> long as at least the most recent message for every key is kept. This
> lets Kafka reclaim storage space while ensuring that the topic
> contains a complete data set and can be used for reloading key-based
> state.
>
> Tombstone events When a row is deleted, the delete event value still
> works with log compaction, because Kafka can remove all earlier
> messages that have that same key. However, for Kafka to remove all
> messages that have that same key, the message value must be null. To
> make this possible, the PostgreSQL connector follows a delete event
> with a special tombstone event that has the same key but a null value.

Does anyone could help me to handle empty message?

Comment: You can check if the event body is not null/empty before calling ```decode``` function on it.

Comment: Hey @AnandSowmithiran. It's not decode that causes the error. It is the iterator. During debug I can see that the exception is generated by second run on the line: `for event in events:`

Comment: Have you tried to ask in the debezium forum as well? The debezium documents talk about messages to kafka topic, doesn't give samples on how to handle the tombstone events.